# AWS SES(Simple Email Service) logging sent email recipients address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses, mail-server

I have deployed an SES solution on my project, a web form, clients have to put their email and they will get an email afterwards. I am being asked to get the list of email addresses, the content of each email, the status of whether it has been delivered or bounced, etc.
I have set a configuration set to start logging the delivery status. Still, I am unable to get the email addresses of recipients and to map if the email sent to that address has reached its destination or not.
I was using mail chimp for this task earlier.
Please guide me a way out.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest to:

- from your form call a lambda function
- in the lambda track in your database the status
- invoke SES
- read the status of SES email and track in your database

Answer (score 1):

We can use this tool to monitor Simple Email Service. All the features and snapshots are in the below-mentioned link.

https://sesdashboard.com/

Availability on AWS Market Place.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-wdrczxbx6gwom

Another option is here however, it will be charged $5 per Month.
https://www.sesmonitor.com/